# Javascript All audio fade out

Tags: javascript, audio, fadeout

I want to fade out all playing audio. I tried *getElementsByTagName* but it seemed not working with audio volume. I have several audios and I named id as numbers. Check my HTML and JS code.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" size="3" value="1" id="numtext" style="font-size:700pt" >

<audio id=1>
    <source src=BGM/a.mp3>
</audio>

<audio id=2>
    <source src=BGM/b.mp3>
</audio>

<audio id=3>
    <source src=BGM/c.mp3>
</audio>
```

**JS**

```
    function fade() {

        var x = document.getElementById('numtext').value;
        var sounds = document.getElementById(x);

        var newVolume = (sounds.volume) - 0.07;

        // Check if the newVolume is greater than zero
        if(newVolume >= 0){
            sounds.volume = newVolume;
        }
        else{
            // Stop fade
        sounds.pause();
        sounds.currentTime = 0;
        sounds.volume = 1;

            clearInterval(interval);
        }

}
```

Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select all the audio's elements like that:

```
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
```

Then you do whatever you want on the audios list

```
    for(i=0;i<audios.length;i++){
      //Do your stuff here on audios[i]
    }
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I don't understand about second code you wrote. What is the code for?

Comment: Its a simple For. It selects the i-th element in the audios' list (The list of all the audios in the html)
Then you have to modify them one by one.
ex: audios[i].volume = 0;

Answer (score 0):

When ever you want to manipulate multiple elements you should **use a class** .

**Example :**

Lets say we give all our audio tags a class of `audio-list`..

```
<audio class="audio-list" id="1">...</audio>
```

**Use case :**

```
var audioList = document.querySelectorAll('.audio-list');
```

**Then :**

```
document.querySelectorAll() will return an array list of elements
```

You will need to loop through your list of audio elements with this `for-loop`

```
for(var i = 0; i > audioList.length ; i++){

    //fadeOut your audio    
}
```

Another suggestion is that if you're playing multiple sounds at once you will
most likely find the audio api to be handy with its audio buffering support and controlling multiple audio channels docs here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer